# Python requests gives lexical JSON error. How to fix this?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to build a dynamic request in python and send it but I'm getting the error - "There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: lexical error: invalid char in json text."

My code:

```
 headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'auth_token ' + auth_token,
}
data = '{\n  "datapoint": {\n    "value": ' + val + ',\n    "metadata": {\n      "   key1": "",\n      "key2": ""\n    }\n  }\n}'
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

However, if I send a hardcoded value, the request is succesful:

```
data = '{\n  "datapoint": {\n    "value": "120",\n    "metadata": {\n      "key1": "",\n      "key2": ""\n    }\n  }\n}'
```

How do I set the value using a variable 'val'?

Comment: Why are you building JSON as a string like that? Quoting and other errors seem inevitable. Use the built in module to serialise Python objects to JSON.

Comment: Oh I used https://curl.trillworks.com/ to convert curl to python requests and that's how it suggested. Anyway, can you link me to how I should be doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using that way to transform data to string, you need `json.dumps()`.

```
import json

data = {"A":1,
        "B":2
                }
to_str = json.dumps(data)
print(type(to_str),to_str)
# <class 'str'> {"A": 1, "B": 2}
```